# Make the Jackson fail on converting double to int during deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I use Jackson to deserialize a JSON to an immutable custom Java object. Here is the class:

```
final class DataPoint {
  private final int count;
  private final int median;

  @JsonCreator
  DataPoint(
      @JsonProperty("count") int count,
      @JsonProperty("median") int median) {
    if (count <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }
    this.count = count;
    this.median = median;
  }

  // getters...
}
```

Here is the JSON I deserialize:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "median": 2
}
```

It works fine. Now, I break the JSON, i.e. replace the integer `median` with the decimal:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "median": 0.1
}
```

Now, I get `count == 1`, and `median == 0`. Instead, I would like the Jackson to fail deserilizing, since the data type of the JSON property `median` and the formal `median` parameter type (an `int`) are different, and the conversion looses the data actually.

Here is the deserializing code:

```
String json = "..."; // the second JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_MISSING_CREATOR_PROPERTIES)
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES)
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE);
DataPoint data = mapper.readValue(json, DataPoint.class);
```

Can I make Jackson fail when deserializing a decimal to an integer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the option `ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` for that purpose. E.g. :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT);
```

And for `"0.1"` you will get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not coerce a
>   floating-point value ('0.1') into Integer; enable
>   `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_FLOAT_AS_INT` to allow

You can see pertinent docs [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#value-conversions-coercion)

Note that this is available since Jackson 2.6

Comment: Thanx a lot! It just works fine. Just a littile pity is `2.0` cannot be converted to `2` with this feature. Anyways, it work much better than I did befoew. Thanx again, dude!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a JSON schema for your JSON document and run validation prior to deserialisation into the Java object.

If you define the `median` property as `integer` type, floating point number will be rejected.

This approach can also solve the problem about allowing `float numbers` that represent `integers` to be accepted too, for example `2.0`. The schema needs to define the `median` property as follows:

```
{
  ...
  "median": { "type": "number", "multipleOf": 1.0 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, RZet! The approach Manos suggested is much easier that defining a JSON schema. Adiitionally, a JSON schema does not solve the problem of successful `2.0` (decimal) to `2` (integer) conversion. Anyways, thanx a lot, dude. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @danissimo Hope my updated post will allow you to kill two birds with one stone lol;